# Ansible task is failing even with the right syntax

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts, ansible-template

I am learning ansible and i have written a task for LDAP validation. However, when i run the playbook, the task is failing even when the validation is correct.

Below is the ansible task which will check for the LDAP password max age

```
- name: LDAP Validation
      shell: /usr/bin/ldapsearch -w admin  -H ldap://localhost:10389 -x -D "cn=manager,dc=apache,dc=com" -b "cn=default,ou=pwpolicies,dc=apache,dc=com" | grep 'pwdMaxAge'
      register: output


- name: LDAP password age check 
  fail:
    msg: "Password MaxAge not set to 0"
  when: output.stdout != "pwdMaxAge: 0"
```

Below is the new syntax error that ansible is throwing after task was updated.

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  mapping values are not allowed here

The error appears to have been in '/etc/ansible/server/roles/LDAP/tasks/ldap.yml': line 40, column 36, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

    msg: "Password MaxAge not set to 0"
  when: output.stdout != "pwdMaxAge: 0"
                                   ^ here
```

Comment: try doing a `- debug: var=output` see the structure of the variable  usualy it's a sub property of the variable that will contain what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `output` is a dictionary; it doesn't make sense to compare it to a string: the comparison will **never** be equal. Take a look at [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html#return-values) to see what values are returned by the `shell` module.

For example, you might end up checking the `stdout` attribute like this:

```
- name: LDAP password age check 
  fail:
    msg: "Password MaxAge not set to 0"
  when: 'output.stdout != "pwdMaxAge: 0"'
```

As @PatrickForget suggested, you can use a `debug` task to inspect your registered variable:

```
- name: show output variable
  debug:
    var: output
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but the ansible task is failing again becoz of syntax even using the backslash before zero.

Comment: Below is the error that ansible throws when executing the playbook. it is showing the error after ":"
`The offending line appears to be:`
   msg: "Password MaxAge not set to 0"
  when: output.stdout != "pwdMaxAge: 0"
                                   ^ here

Comment: Have you added a `debug` task to verify what the contents of `output` look like? Please update your question to show that in the playbook as well as the resulting output.

Comment: It's the `:` in your string: put quotes around the entire `when` expression.  I've updated this answer (and verified that it validates).

Comment: Thanks larsks and others.